# Flutter: How to know if my widget is inside another widget of a specific type?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing a Widget called `TopBar`, and associated with it is another Widget called `TopBarAction`. I need to know if `TopBarAction` is being used inside `TopBar` or not in order to use an `Align` or `Positioned` widget in its build method:

```
class TopBar extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<Widget> actions;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final Alignment actionsAlignment;

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MediaQueryData moc = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return LimitedBox(
      maxWidth: moc.size.width,
      maxHeight: moc.size.height,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: actionsAlignment,
        children: actions,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopBarAction extends StatelessWidget {

  final Widget title;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final EdgeInsets? padding;
  final Alignment? actionAlignment;

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isParentTopBar = false;
    context.visitAncestorElements((element) { <-------- Is this the right way to do it??
      if (element.widget is TopBar) {
        isParentTopBar = true;
      }
      return false; // return false to stop visiting other widgets. Only visit the direct parent.
    });
    late Widget child;
    child = Padding(
      padding: padding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: title,
      ),
    );
    if (actionAlignment != null && isParentTopBar) {
      child = Align(
        alignment: actionAlignment!,
        child: child,
      );
    }
    return child;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`visitAncestorElements` may get very [expensive](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/visitAncestorElements.html) but in your case you're just adding an additional visit to the parent node, and that *might* be ok.

But I'd suggest the following to simplify your code and to prevent the use of `visitAncestorElements`.

```dart
class TopBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopBar({
    required this.actions,
    required this.padding,
    required this.actionsAlignment,
    super.key,
  });

  final List<Widget> actions;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final Alignment actionsAlignment;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final moc = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return LimitedBox(
      maxWidth: moc.size.width,
      maxHeight: moc.size.height,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: actionsAlignment,
        children: [
          for (final a in actions)
            if (a is TopBarAction)
              Align(
                alignment: actionsAlignment,
                child: a,
              )
            else
              Padding(padding: padding, child: a)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopBarAction extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopBarAction({
    required this.title,
    required this.onTap,
    super.key,
  });

  final Widget title;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: title,
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if i've understood what you need.

Comment: your approach removes the property from the child and moves it to the parent, and this does not answer my question. I want in the child to check if its in the right parent to do some widget wrapping on the child. I already found a way to do it (as mentoned int the question above) but I need to know if its the best way to go. thx anw for the answer.

Comment: This is exactly why I've done that in my answer - you're using Flutter and "checking the parent to see if the child needs additional properties" means fighting against the Framework. You're in a bad path in this moment and this is why I've moved the logic up top and let the parents *pass such properties down to the children*. Maybe I didn't precisely understand what you need in your case but that's the way to use Flutter

Comment: yes I think you may be right in that I may be fighting the framework, but anyway the answer does not answer the question so I cannot accept it, thx anyway :)